# how to get the PreferenceStore in XText generated plugin

Tags: eclipse, xtext, emf

I am trying to extend the preference pages generated by XText for a DSL. I have managed to add a new Preference Page which exploits field editors but I can't see how to get the `IPreferenceStore` instance in order to keep track of the modified configuration as described in http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html

Answer (score 0):

The `IPreferenceStore` can be injected (see the [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/302_configuration.html#dependency-injection)):

```
        <page
            category="org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl"
            class="org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.MyDslExecutableExtensionFactory:org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.MyPage"
            id="org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl.coloring"
            name="MyPage">
            <keywordReference id="org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.keyword_MyDsl"/>
        </page>
```

With e.g.

```
public class MyPage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage {
    @Inject
    public MyPage (IPreferenceStore preferenceStore) {
        setPreferenceStore(preferenceStore);
    }
}
```